# Avoid duplicate items Python

Tags: python, code-duplication, items

I am having an issue with duplicate items in a list in python.

For example I have this list

```
i = ['hello', 'hi', 'bye', 'welcome', 'hi', 'bye']
```

I want to print every item once, even if it's duplicated print it once.

Is there any way to do it in python?

Comment: Does the order matters?

Comment: You can [remove duplicate items from the list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists), of course. There are various other ways to print each item once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order doesn't matters, then you can use a `set`:

```
print(set(i))
```

Otherwise you can do something like this:

```
seen = set()
for e in i:
    if e not in seen:
        print(e)
        seen.add(e)
```

Comment: I think set() is more than enough thank you